# R chart by date

Tags: r, dataframe

I've got transactional data from a SQL query which I turn into a data frame. The first column of the df contains UNIX timestamps (format="%Y/%d/%m %H:%M") which I would like to use to create a graphics plot using par to display 1 unique lineplot per date. At the moment I am fumbling around with splitting column 1 and comparing with previous row to look for a change then assigning a dummy indicator to use in my plot command. 
Thanks,
Will

Comment: add some sample data and the code you tried. That's a lot easier to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat hard to answer without any example data but I'll take a shot.

I'm guessing your date looks like this: `"2009-03-04 17:45"`

It's probably being read as character. You can verify the class of each column of your data frame by running `str(data.frame)`

Using package stringr, you can just read the y/d/m and convert that to a Date class like so:

```
library(stringr)
date="2009-03-04 17:45"
date=as.Date(str_replace_all(str_sub(date,3,10),"-","/"), "%y/%d/%m")
```

You can then use `date` as a group in `ggplot2` to plot one line per date. You could also create separate panels (one per date) using `+ facet_wrap(~date)` in your ggplot call.

Comment: I am known for my convoluted solutions. ;)

Answer (score 1):

1. start by just getting the date part from your timestamp

   SELECT *,DATE(timestampcolumn) as thedate FROM yourtable;
2. Convert date column to factor

   mydf <- transform(mydf,as.factor(thedate))
3. Plot it with e.g. xyplot

   library(lattice)
   xyplot(varx~vary|thedate,data=mydf)